# How can I count the documents in an array depending on their value in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to count the number of parking spaces _id: 5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23, which has the false value in the excluded property, how can I mount the query?

So far, I've been able to select the number of parking spaces with the excluded: false property. But are selecting from all parking lots

Note that there are two documents symbolizing a parking lot, where each has an array, called parkingSpaces, to record parking space documents.

The first document has 2 vacancies not excluded, so with the property excluded: false and the second has only one vacancy, which is not excluded either.

```
{
        "_id": "5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23",
        "name": "estacionamento um",
        "parkingSpace": [
            {
                "_id": "5d752cf54f4f1c0f1c93eb26",
                "name": "vg001",
                "excluded": true

            },
            {
                "_id": "5d752cf54f4f1c0f1c93eb27",
                "name": "vg001",
                "excluded": false

            },
            {
                "_id": "5d75339bc411423a9c14ac52",
                "name": "vg002",
                "excluded": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d7706b60d354b72388a38f4",
        "name": "estacionamento dois",
        "parkingSpace": [
            {
                "_id": "5d77078a5173bb63bc87b7ca",
                "name": "vg004",
                "excluded": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to add the number of parking spaces _id: 5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23, which has the value false in the excluded property.

In the end, I need to return the value 2, referring to _id: 5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23 parking spaces, which have the value false in the excluded property.

So far, with the following query, I was able to select the vacancies with the excluded property with the false value, but it is selecting from all parking lots.

```
const registeredParkingSpaces = await Parking.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$parkingSpace' },
        { $match: { 'parkingSpace.excluded': false } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: parking_id,
                total: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
 ]);
```

returns:

```
{
  "message": [
    {
      "_id": "5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23",
      "total": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

But it needs to return:

```
{
  "message": [
    {
      "_id": "5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23",
      "total": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: in fact he needs to return only one, because one of the vacancies, is with the property excluded:true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In aggregation 1st you match with id then go for the next step you will get your desire count because at this moment you are considering entire document "parkingSpace". Below is the sample code I guess it will work for you

```
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
const registeredParkingSpaces = await Parking.aggregate([
        { $match: { _id: objectId(body.id) } }
        { $unwind: '$parkingSpace' },
        { $match: { 'parkingSpace.excluded': false } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: parking_id,
                total: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
 ]);
```

Comment: I tested it here and it worked, thanks.
It worked with the first and second _id. I added more parking spaces, excluded and not excluded, and it worked: D

Answer (score 0):

This is the query through which you can get the count of total parking .

** UPDATED **

```
      db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "parkingSpace.excluded": false,

    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      parkingSpace: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "count": {
        "$sum": {
          "$size": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$parkingSpace",
              "as": "el",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$el.excluded",
                  false
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can check the solution from this **[LINK](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DYwOmxZh4rL)**
For more information about $sum : Visit the official [official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) 

Through this you get your solution .

Comment: But as I have more than one job deleted, it keeps returning "1" [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ANLTcrWVwsN)

Comment: I need to count the parking spaces with the excluded: false parking property with _id: '5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23'. In this case, the document has 3 vacancies, two with the property excluded: false

Comment: Now check out the final code . This is what you want . @RaulGermano